# Applescript to hide print queue

Tags: applescript, automator, printing, folder-action

Running a Processing sketch which saves .txt files to a folder. Have a folder action attached that prints new files in this folder to a thermal receipt printer.

However, I had to update to Yosemite, and since then the print queue window opens up over the sketch and has to be closed manually before continuing with the sketch.
When I print a document normally the printer proxy behaves and stays in the dock, and doesn't change focus from Processing.

I have no Applescript experience, but I think I need a script that I could include in the folder action, so these .txt files print automatically, without intervention while Processing is running.

Answer (score 1):

One idea that comes to mind is to use the command line tools to print the files. If the files are sent to the printer without any pre-processing - in other words raw - then the following command should do it...

`lp  somefile.txt` - if your printer is the default

or

`lp -d MyPrinter somefile.txt` - for non-default printer

Use `lpstat -a` to get a list of printers and their Unix names.

From applescript you would have to do it this way...

```
set pFile to POSIX path of txtFile
do shell script "lp " & quoted form of pFile
```